# Undefined reference when linking one dynamic library into the other using CMake and Cygwin

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, cygwin, undefined-reference

I've looked around, and it doesn't seem that the solution to my problem has been discussed anywhere. So, I write here.

I create a CMake project for generation of several Python libraries. I use Boost.Python to wrap my C++ code, CMake to build dynamic libraries. Everything is on Cygwin platform. The topmost level of the project is pretty standard- eventually it leads to the source directory via:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("src")
```

The /src directory contains two sub-folders - mmath and ann - each is intended for its own library. The CMake file at this level is:

```
MESSAGE("Going into subdirectory mmath...")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("mmath")
MESSAGE("Going into subdirectory ann...")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("ann")
```

So we build the mmath library first:

```
file(GLOB MMATH_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
file(GLOB MMATH_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp ${MMATH_HEADERS}) 
SET( ext_libs 
     ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
     ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}/libpython2.6.dll
   )
ADD_LIBRARY(mmath SHARED ${MMATH_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mmath ${ext_libs})
```

and it works perfectly. The resulting dynamic library can then be imported in Python as a module (in cygwin the library is prepended with "cyg" prefix, instead of "lib"). Among other things, the library defines a class DATA, which is essentially a customized container (a collection of variables of standard types), so very simple. 
Now, when CMake proceeds into the /src/ann directory, it tries to build the corresponding cygann.dll (cygwin convention) library, which depends on the mmath library we have built already. The CMake script is:

```
file(GLOB ANN_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
file(GLOB ANN_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp ${ANN_HEADERS}) 
SET( ext_libs1
     mmath
     ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
     ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}/libpython2.6.dll
   )
ADD_LIBRARY(ann SHARED ${ANN_SRC})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ann ${ext_libs1})
```

In the src/ann directory we have a file defining the class Ann, which has the members of type std::vector. It is here where linking problem revels itself: the DATA class causes some problems on the linking stage - the "undefined reference" error. The errors indicate that neither constructor nor destructor for the DATA class are defined:

```
CMakeFiles/ann.dir/libann.cpp.o: In function `Destroy<libmmath::DATA>':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:93: undefined reference to `libmmath::DATA::~DATA()'

CMakeFiles/ann.dir/libann.cpp.o: In function `Construct<libmmath::DATA, libmmath::DATA>':
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:83: undefined reference to `libmmath::DATA::DATA(libmmath::DATA const&)'
```

So I'm wondering what could be the problem. Is this related to CMake features, cygwin tricks or is it something regarding the code itself? Well, i feel that the problem is less likely related to the code itself, since it works in standard utilization (static exe or just a single dynamic library). It is more likely that it is something about CMake or cygwin that I'm missing.  But what? Please, help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is that he can't find anywhere `libmmath` (but with gcc you'd do a `-L/path/to/lib`). It may not work because you do not add or link libmmath when you build ANN.

Comment: well, the libmmath is supposed to be added automatically, since I add the mmath target as one of the dependencies of the ann target/library: TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ann ${ext_libs1}) - you can see that mmath is included in the definition of ext_libs1 variable

Comment: Is the DATA class part of the dll export set? Use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to double-check.

Comment: well, it is better to think of .so files - dll is just the name the dynamic libs are called in cygwin. Apart from that, yes, I export DATA class as well - using Boost.Python: e.g.  class_<DATA>("DATA",init<>())
                                         .def(init<boost::python::list>())

Comment: by the way, I've found that when I ask for a static libraries build - all works fine, although this is not helpful for interfacing the c++ code with Python. It looks like the cyg- prefix Cygwin uses for dynamic libraries, could be the source of the problem. In contrast, the static library names are still prepended with "lib" prefix, which is possible reason why compilation of static libraries goes well. Now I'm looking to building static version of mmath and linking it into dynamic version of ann. Or, perhaps, some ideas on how to make cygwin use more conventional prefixes would be useful.